# Ruby on Rails link tag in <a> not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I created an simple site, where the user can view different documents (uploaded with carrierwave (thumb version) in an table, and when he clicks on one, an modal view should open (fancybox) and display the normal version of the picture:

[image]

The picture displayed in the table

[image]

Then when the modal view opens, it shows the (:thumb version) and not the full width/height version

[image]

And my biggest problem is that, after the user closed the model view, the picture is not anymore displayed in the table!

I am pretty sure that the cause for my problems is how I made my links in the code:

```
 <% treatment.paintings.each do |paint| %>                          
        <a class="fancybox" link_to 'paint.name.url'> <%= image_tag  paint.name.url(:thumb)%></a>
 <% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the line

```
<a class="fancybox" link_to 'paint.name.url'> <%= image_tag  paint.name.url(:thumb)%></a>
```

with

```
<%= link_to image_tag(paint.name.thumb.url), paint.name.url, class: 'fancybox' %>
```

Comment: why are you using old syntax?

Answer (score 2):

link_to is helper for a-tag. http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to
Why do you use link_to inside a-tag?